# cron expression to 0-8am = 3 minutes and 9-23 = 1 hour

Tags: node.js, cron

How to create expression will run `0-8am = 3 minutes` and `9-23pm = 1 hour`.

Example, expression run per `3 minutes =  '*/3 * * * *'` and i want every `3 minutes` and `1 hour`.

Comment: Let me get it right , you want a cron to be run every 3 minstues from 0 am to 8 am and another cron to be run every 1 hour from 9 am to 11 pm right?? @komarudin

Comment: improved formatting

Comment: yes. i mean like that. but i want run on singel cron expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do such thing with a single cron expression. You will have to use two separated expressions :

Every 3 minutes from 0am to 8am : `*/3 0-8 * * *`

Every hour from 9am to 11pm : `0 9-23 * * *`

Comment: No sorry. Or else, you should have to run it every 3 minutes (`*/3 * * * *`), and then check in your script (executed by the cron) in which case you are. Case 1 (0am-8am) : execute the script normally. Case 2 (9am-23pm) : Execute the script only once per hour, meaning you should store somewhere when you executed the cron last time (database, file, ...). In my opinion this way is way more complicated than the first one.

Comment: oh i see. i check by if at 9-23 just run once an hour. but cron still every 3 minutes. thanks for your sugesstion.